# Create a window using the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE flag ,but it can't be dragged until I release the mouse

Tags: c++, windows, drag

I have created a window using the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE flag and it works great as far as not taking focus when you click the window. However when I drag the window or try to resize it, it doesn't redraw the window as your are moving and resizing it, only at the very end once you release the mouse button. Is there a way around this? I would like to see the window as I am resizing it. I have searched many documents, but I still don't find the resolution...

Answer (score 2):

If you need a window that doesn't take focus when clicked, but can still be interacted with, you need to handle the [WM_MOUSEACTIVATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645612.aspx), and return `MA_NOACTIVATE`.

Additional information and fully working sample code has been published by Raymond Chen. See [How can I have a window that rejects activation but still receives pointer input?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160912-00/?p=94295)

Answer (score 1):

It's a Windows bug. You need to call `SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, x, y, width, height, 0)` on `WM_MOVING`. The coordinates to set are given to you in `lParam` which is a `RECT*`.

Note that doing this will activate the owned window and deactivate the owner, which is not what you want (and `SWP_NOACTIVATE` has no effect either).

To avoid that, you need to set WS_CHILD on the owned window. But set it **after** you created the window, via SetWindowLong(), otherwise your owned window will get clipped, like any child window.

And, as you probably already figured out, this only works for windows with `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` ex style. I wasn't able to make the owned window stay deactivated with any other style combination that doesn't include `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`.

That's winapi for you :(

Comment: Do you have any reference that agrees with you, that this is indeed a defect in Windows? As for setting the `WS_CHILD` window style on an owned window, that's just ludicrous. Turning an owned window **halfway** into a child window is neither documented to work, nor is it even clear, what should happen (is the window owned or a child window?). This sounds like very dangerous advice.

Comment: I documented all the bugs related to non-activable toolbox windows here:  https://github.com/luapower/nw/blob/master/nw_winapi.lua -- these are empirically found bugs, there's no reference but _reality_ agrees with me.

Comment: When I said *"any reference that agrees with you"* I didn't mean another document authored by yourself. I was after something more official, like a Microsoft Connect incident.

Comment: more notes scattered around in these links: https://github.com/luapower/winapi/blob/master/winapi/window.lua https://github.com/luapower/winapi/blob/master/winapi/windowclass.lua https://github.com/luapower/winapi/blob/master/winapi/basewindowclass.lua

Comment: *Github* and *official* have zero overlap.

Comment: Then the answer is no. But feel free to contradict me with _working code_, i.e. show me a WS_EX_NOACTIVATE that shows-contents-while-dragging without the aforementioned workarounds in my answer.

Comment: I'm not questioning your observations. I'm questioning, whether this is a bug, or (documented) behavior. Since you called it a bug, I was hoping, that this is based on something a bit more solid than thin air.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, just "thin air" here.