# How can I avoid a form getting focus when dragged

Tags: delphi, window, focus

I have a simple form that only contains a `TTouchKeyboard`. The forms `BorderStyle` is set to `bsToolWindow`. To avoid the form getting focus when clicking the touch keyboard I handle the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message with this implementation:

```
procedure TKeyboardForm.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;
```

The `BorderStyle` setting allows the form to be dragged with the title bar, but in that case the form still gets the focus. Is there a way to avoid this?

**Update:** I tried adding WS_EX_NOACTIVATE to ExStyle in CreateParams, but unfortunately that doesn't hinder the form to receive focus when dragged.

```
procedure TKeyboardForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe these will help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051552/create-a-window-using-the-ws-ex-noactivate-flag-but-it-cant-be-dragged-until-i

Comment: Yes, adding `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` to your `ExStyle`in `TForm.CreateParams(..)` should do it. The form can still be dragged but it will not steal focus from another app. You won't even need your `TWMMouseActivate` handler.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful: Thanks guys, but unfortunately that doesn't help.

Comment: I was looking now in our Sources, so i can not post code but try
WM_NCACTIVATE and there 
 SetWindowPos(Handle, ParentHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE);

Comment: @Fritzw, still no success.

Comment: @Fritzw did you actually make this work with the title bar? I also tried the WM_NCACTIVATE with no success. How do you handle this massage? Don't post code if you cant but give us some real guidlines...

Comment: @kobik read the msn for the messge, the only we have added is the call i posted, but i'm not on a pc now. And it will work for the titlebar. I will try to make a example tomorow.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid, does it stay focused after the drag?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, the goal is that I can drag the form with the touch keyboard around while the focus stays in the edit field of another form. I could live with a solution where the edit field automatically gets the focus back after the drag.

Comment: Perhaps you can save/restore focus with `WM_[ENTER|EXIT]SIZEMOVE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following combination of `WMMouseActivate()`, `WMNCActivate()` and reseting focus seems to fulfill your wishes:

The keyboard form (with `BorderStyle = bsToolWindow`) has message handlers for `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` (as you already have) and `WM_NCACTIVATE`. The latter for having a point where to reset focus to the window with the edit control.

In addition the keyboardform will keep track of which form holds the edit (or other) control that has focus, and does that by introducing a new method for showing, which I called `ShowUnfocused()` and a field called `FocusedForm: THandle`.

```
procedure TKbdForm.ShowUnfocused(FocusedWindow: THandle);
begin
  FocusedForm := FocusedWindow;
  Show;
end;

procedure TKbdForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetForegroundWindow(FocusedForm);
end;

procedure TKbdForm.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;

procedure TKbdForm.WMNCActivate(var Message: TWMNCActivate);
begin
  Message.Result := 1; // important
  SetForegroundWindow(FocusedForm);
end;
```

The keyboardform is invoked by the following common code of the edit controls:

```
procedure TForm17.EditClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  KbdForm.ShowUnfocused(self.Handle);
  (Sender as TWinControl).SetFocus;
end;
```

An alternative to what is said above, could be to set the `BorderStyle = bsNone` and arrange the dragging of the form with the `Mouse Down, Move, Up` events directly from the forms surface (or maybe a panel to mimic a top frame), and adding a close button. The challenge would be to get it visually acceptable.

Comment: Although I kind of don't like the fact that I have to update the FocusedForm variable manually (BTW, a similar approach was brought to me from @Fritzw via email), I am going to accept this answer just for the fact that it showed me the direction I had to go.

Answer (score 3):

Because I was not very pleased with the approach that requires me to manually update the focused form variable in the keyboard form, I searched for a more transparent solution and came up with this approach.

**Update:** The previous approach had some issues with VCL styles. In addition not all of the message handlers were really necessary, though others turned out to be helpful, too. This version works well with VCL styles avoiding any flicker as far as possible:

```
type
  TKeyboardForm = class(TForm)
    TouchKeyboard1: TTouchKeyboard;
  private
    FLastFocusedForm: TCustomForm;
    procedure SetLastFocusedForm(const Value: TCustomForm);
  protected
    procedure WMActivate(var Message: TWMActivate); message WM_ACTIVATE;
    procedure WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate); message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE;
    procedure WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus); message WM_SETFOCUS;
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
    property LastFocusedForm: TCustomForm read FLastFocusedForm write SetLastFocusedForm;
  public
    class constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function SetFocusedControl(Control: TWinControl): Boolean; override;
  end;

type
  TKeyboardFormStyleHook = class(TFormStyleHook)
  protected
    procedure WMNCActivate(var Message: TWMNCActivate); message WM_NCACTIVATE;
  end;

procedure TKeyboardFormStyleHook.WMNCActivate(var Message: TWMNCActivate);
begin
  { avoids the title bar being drawn active for blink }
  Message.Active := False;
  inherited;
end;

class constructor TKeyboardForm.Create;
begin
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TKeyboardForm, TKeyboardFormStyleHook);
end;

destructor TKeyboardForm.Destroy;
begin
  LastFocusedForm := nil;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TKeyboardForm.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FLastFocusedForm) then begin
    FLastFocusedForm := nil;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

function TKeyboardForm.SetFocusedControl(Control: TWinControl): Boolean;
begin
  LastFocusedForm := Screen.FocusedForm;
  result := inherited;
end;

procedure TKeyboardForm.SetLastFocusedForm(const Value: TCustomForm);
begin
  if FLastFocusedForm <> Value then
  begin
    if FLastFocusedForm <> nil then begin
      FLastFocusedForm.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
    end;
    FLastFocusedForm := Value;
    if FLastFocusedForm <> nil then begin
      FLastFocusedForm.FreeNotification(Self);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TKeyboardForm.WMActivate(var Message: TWMActivate);
begin
  Message.Active := WA_INACTIVE;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TKeyboardForm.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  inherited;
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;

procedure TKeyboardForm.WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus);
begin
  inherited;
  if (FLastFocusedForm <> nil) and (message.FocusedWnd <> FLastFocusedForm.Handle) then begin
    SendMessage(FLastFocusedForm.Handle, WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0);
    Message.FocusedWnd := FLastFocusedForm.Handle;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Very nice +1, but don't you need to set `WndParent` to the active form handle in `TKeyboardForm.CreateParams` (or use `GWL_HWNDPARENT`)? or is the `TKeyboardForm` an always on top form? I also don't understand your last modification. why do you call `inherited` in the `WMSetFocus`/`WMMouseActivate`/`WMActivate`? wouldn't that use the original handler?

Comment: @kobik, I have to admit that most of the code is a result of trial and error. The WMActivate just switches the active state of the message letting the inherited think the window is deactivated. Thus the window is never drawn active. The calls to inherited were necessary to execute the style hook events properly. It is still possible that less code may be sufficient, but I stopped researching when the desired results were achieved. Although, sometimes there is still a short flicker in the title bar of the previously focused window.

Comment: OK, I didn't take VCL styles into account. this indeed causes a tiny flicker. How about that `WndParent`? is the keyboard form in front of the focused form?

Comment: @kobik, yes the keyboard form is fsStayOnTop. But you are right: even with that setting the keyboard form is behind a modal window. Investigating...